# Swift for in loop with parentheses

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I normally use the for in loop in swift without parentheses, but today I put them on just for kicks thinking they were just optional and it did not worked as expected.

This code works:

```
if let tasks = getAllTasksWithManagedObjectContext(appDelegate.managedObjectContext){
    for task in tasks{
        appDelegate.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(task)
    }
}
```

This one does not:

```
if let tasks = getAllTasksWithManagedObjectContext(appDelegate.managedObjectContext){
    for (task in tasks){
        appDelegate.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(task)
    }
}
```

I get this errors:
[image]
Whats going on here?

Comment: You can put parentheses around everything after `in` but you cannot do it as you have above, at least not in Swift. You could do `for task in (tasks)` for example. The compiler reads that `(task in tasks)` as one isolated computation or object or whatever, and doesn't recognize the `in` as part of the `for loop`

Comment: I think Swift compiler's error message for this case needs improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are simply not allowed to use parentheses here.

Take a look at the [`Language Reference -> Statements`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/loop-statement) and compare the `C-style for-loop` against the `swift for-in`

> for-statement → for­ `for-init`­;`­expression­`;­`expression­` `­code-block`
>   for-statement → for­ (`for-init`­;`­expression­`;­`expression­`) `­code-block`

vs.

> for-in-statement → for `­case`(opt) ­`pattern` ­in `­expression` `­where-clause­`(opt­) `code-block`

The first one can be used with or without parentheses - your choice as the developer.

However the later one, the one you are actually asking about does not have a version with `(` and `)`, only the one version without them. That means that it is not allowed to use them parentheses around the "argument" of the loop.

*Screenshots from the docs linked above for better readability:*

[image]
vs.
[image]